# Kivy not Allowing me to use full screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a Kivy MP3 player type app but for some reason I'm not allowed to use my full screen ie. when my code looks like this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.lang import Builder
class Application(App):
    def build(self):
       
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
       
        img = Image(source='myapp/logo1.png',size_hint=(1, .5),pos_hint={'center_x':0.7,"center_y":1},allow_stretch=True)
        button = Button(text="Click Here For Some Sweet Music",size_hint=(0.5,0.5),background_color=color,pos_hint={'center_x':0.7})
        button.bind(on_press=self.on_button_press)
        layout.add_widget(img)
        layout.add_widget(button)

Application().run()
```

I get a screen looking like
[image]
but when I move the center x of the image to 1 I get an image looking like
[image]
So there is an "imaginary" box inside the window.
I've tried changing the Config settings but it doesn't work.
How would I make this box larger?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Done. The code should work and the image can be replaced with another.

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` is not the full width of the window because of the `size_hint` that you have assigned. The `Image` is not the full width because the `Image`, by default,  tries to maintain the aspect ratio of the `source` image. You can fill the entire window y adjusting `size_hint` and changing `keep_ratio`:

```
class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        img = Image(source='myapp/logo1.png', size_hint=(1, .5), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5},
                    allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        button = Button(text="Click Here For Some Sweet Music", size_hint=(1.0, 0.5),
                        pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5})
        button.bind(on_press=self.on_button_press)
        layout.add_widget(img)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        return layout
```